# How to reference 2 output files in rule

Tags: makefile

So I have the following Makefile snippet:

```
OUTPUT = f1  f2

$(OUTPUT) : $SOURCES
    $(PROCESSOR)  -i $SOURCES -o $@
```

My intention is to name 2 output files:  `$(PROCESSOR) -i $SOURCES  -o f1  f2`
, but make interprets it to be 2 separate commands:

```
$(PROCESSOR) -i $SOURCES  -o f1
$(PROCESSOR) -i $SOURCES  -o f2
```

So how can I give 2 outputs here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this calls for a pattern rule with multiple targets, e.g.,

```
OUTPUT = f1 f2

%1 %2: $(SOURCES)
    $(PROCESSOR) -i $(SOURCES) -o $*1 $*2
```

which, unlike normal rules, will not be translated into two separate rules. Note that the two output file names need to have a common stem for this to work.